# SVG doesn't render on screen, console log shows "false" suggesting promise was rejected

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

Not sure why my SVG is not rendering in the screen. The console log says "false" which I assume means that a promise was rejected

This is my TS file

```
export class PieChartComponent implements AfterViewInit {
//other initializations removed for brevity
  convertedData: Map<string, number> = new Map();

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    d3.csv('app/data/data.csv').then((data) => {
      data.forEach((d) => {
        this.convertedData.set(d['name'], Number(d['age']));
      });
    });

    this.svg = d3
      .select('#canvas-area')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', 400)
      .attr('height', 400);

    this.circles = this.svg.selectAll('circle').data(this.convertedData);

    this.circles
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('cx', (d, i) => i * 50 + 50)
      .attr('cy', 250)
      .attr('r', (d) => 2 * d[0])
      .attr('fill', (d) => {
        if (d[1] == 'Jessica') return 'blue';
        return 'red';
      });
  }
}
```

And, this is my HTML file:

```
<div id="canvas-area"></div>
```

My data.csv file basically has this:

```
name,age
Tony,10
Jessica,12
Andrew,9
Emily,10
Richard,11
```

Answer (score 0):

`d3.csv()` is a promise but you are not awaiting its completion, so `this.convertedData` is most probably empty when you try to use it.

You need to update your code to something like this:

```
async ngAfterViewInit() {
  await d3.csv('app/data/data.csv').then((data) => {
    data.forEach((d) => {
      this.convertedData.set(d['name'], Number(d['age']));
    });
  });

  // the rest of your code
}
```